# Maintain use of non-digested assets url with rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

In upgrading to `rails 5`, some legacy asset urls needed to be converted from from an explicit form like  `/assets/pretty_image.png` to `image_url('pretty_image.png')`.  This a straight forward change and allows proper caching.  But there are emails out there with the old form url. Is there anyway I can continue to let urls like `/assets/pretty_image.png` still work in production?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is a problem with upgrading from rails 4, which stopped allowing both digested and non-digested assets being used. For some reason, the problem did not appear in production until I upgraded to rails 5.

There is a good discussion of some possible solutions [here](https://bibwild.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/non-digested-asset-names-in-rails-4-your-options/). I used the solution entitled 'Use the Manifest, Rake'.  I needed to change from pre-compiling on Heroku to precompiling in development to get  the solution to work. I am interested in a solution that still allows precompiling on Heroku.